# Pyomo closes Excel

Tags: python, excel, pyomo

Whenever I run a python script from cmd prompt containing the following
    from pyomo.environ import *
any open instance of excel closes. I have no idea why this is happening? Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with how Pyomo (really PyUtilib) interacts with Excel on Windows (see https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/355).  If you plan to use Pyomo with Excel, there really isn't a workaround.  If you are OK with disabling support for Pyomo's excel-specific data import mechanisms, then you can work around this bug by editing `pyomo/core/plugins/data/sheet.py` and disabling the following code:

```
if win32com_available:
    from pyutilib.excel.spreadsheet_win32com import ExcelSpreadsheet_win32com
    tmp = ExcelSpreadsheet_win32com()
    try:
        tmp._excel_dispatch()
        tmp._excel_quit()
        _excel_available = True
    except:
        pass
```

(The simplest thing to do is change `if win32com_available:` to `if False:`)